# How google bigquery calculate the memory needed before running the query?

Tags: google-bigquery

What is the algorithm that google bigquery uses to instantly calculate the memory needed to run the query even before running the query?

Comment: I do not think, that BigQuery calculates the needed memory before running the query. For each node, on which some data of the quered tables is stored, has to to a task. There is a memory limit and if this is exceeded the query is stopped. The billing bytes can be fast calculated by BigQuery: It only needs to sum up the sizes of each column in each partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly overkill for the question, but [this research paper from 2021](http://vldb.org/pvldb/vol14/p3083-edara.pdf) has a lot of background information about BigQuery's metadata layer.